# Finding Average in row

Tags: excel, row, average

Ok, so I have a report with multiple individuals and results for different months. I am trying to see average of 3 months at a time, but each have different starting months. How would I do this?

Example:

- NameA: Results will be average of Feb-Apr, then May-July
- NameB: Results would be Jan-March etc
- NameC: Results March-May

My graph is horrible sorry no pics allowed

```
|Name|Jan|Feb|March|April|May|
| A  |   | 2 |  9  |  6  | 1 |
| B  | 1 | 8 |  9  |  4  | 3 |
| C  |   |   |  1  |  9  | 3 |
```

Comment: You can put the link of a picture in your question though, and someone can come along and put it properly in your question. Do the results for each name end in different months or something?

Comment: Does it only cover 1 year? Where do you want the averages? Are you trying to avoid macros?

Comment: Once there is a starting month will all following months have values, no blanks after the first non blank value?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works:

```
    Sub add_averages()
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, right_c As Long
        r = 2
        Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("a" & r))
            c = 2
            'find first non-empty cell in row
            Do While IsEmpty(Cells(r, c)) And c <= 6
                c = c + 1
            Loop
            If c <= 6 Then
                dest_c = 7
                right_c = c + 2
                If right_c > 6 Then right_c = 6
                Cells(r, dest_c).Value = average_cells(r, c, right_c)
                If right_c < 6 Then
                    dest_c = dest_c + 1
                    c = c + 3
                    right_c = c + 2
                    If right_c > 6 Then right_c = 6
                    Cells(r, dest_c).Value = average_cells(r, c, right_c)
                End If
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Function average_cells(r As Long, left_c As Long, right_c As Long) As Single
        'handles up to three numbers
        If left_c = right_c Then
            average_cells = Cells(r, left_c).Value
        ElseIf left_c + 1 = right_c Then
            average_cells = (Cells(r, left_c).Value + Cells(r, right_c).Value) / 2
        Else
            average_cells = (Cells(r, left_c).Value + Cells(r, left_c + 1).Value + Cells(r, right_c).Value) / 3
        End If
    End Function
```

It assumes that you want to put the resultant averages in columns G and H. Referring to the columns as numbers, I couldn't quite use the existing average functions the way I wanted to, so I wrote my own.

Hope this helps~